Position on postmodern philosophy in modern society
Let's say, there's some author. Baudrillard or Deleuze or whatever. A lot of people read them. Some of them more or less can understand what they write about.
And there's a university system that teaches people philosophy, students and professors talking about what they read and what the authors meant and so on.
But isn't this position to "teach" philosophy in general is kind of contrary to what Deleuze was writing about for example?
Let's say there's a general person, who lives his life, doing whatever he does, reads Deleuze in spare time, just like million other people around him. And there's some philosophy major who also reads Deleuze, writes articles about what he reads and that's it.
And this philosophy major is treated by society pretty well. He gets paid for his "reviews", he is considered a rather attractive intellectual person. But he doesn't really do anything special compared to a general person who also reads Deleuze but doesn't write articles/teach about it. Doesn't the philosophy major basically discriminate this general person from the population? With teaching/writing reviews the philosophy major in a way appropriates "philosophy" for himself, exploiting it? Instead of normalizing situation where people do philosophy, make new things, where new ways of thinking are expected from people? I mean, what is it that really distinguishes such person from other people? Such a person creates a situation, where he receives some privilege for pretty empty routine gestures like repeating what he read, think about something, literally just what's called "living a life" and deprives people just like himself who also reads Deleuze and do not write blogposts about it of the same privilege. It really does seem like something driven by the desire to place yourself above other people, or rather maintain this privileged status quo a person happen to be in. Doesn't it contradict quite a few points the Deleuze for example was making about territorialization, being part of hierarchical systems, exploiting power, etc?
A lot of "postmodern" themes seem to be not really compatible with modern society. The similar thing I would say is with Baudrillard and "modern artists" who talk about Baudrillard and so on.

I think this question is about the psychological experience of social patterns, and more specifically, social status games. The only theory I have read attributed in part or in full to Deleuze is an idea from Anti-Oedipus. The authors criticize Sigmund Freud's psychoanalysis because he argues that society makes the person "sick" (Civilization and Its Discontents) and then psychoanalysis tries to make the person "healthy" by sublimating the ego to the demands of society! Freud says love and prosocial work in society are marks of a healthy ego. Freud also plays status games in his public career.

In the US population, less than 0.05% can write philosophical papers. Let them get paid.

@TheMatrixEquation-balance Idk about US, but where I am, "postmodern" philosophy has become kind of a cult among young people with bloggers, youtubers, etc. Ofc a very small percent actually read anything and write papers, but it's not some kind of a niche thing with anxious people like it always was.

Cult and young people - this is most likely a misuse of the word philosophy. Nowadays, real philosophy is an exclusive club for mature people.

The post concludes as if the post demonstrates that postmodernism is not compatible with society.  But the focus of the post is an argument that could be aimed at majors in a wide range of subjects: literature, psychology, anthorpology.  IOW it's a kind of criqitue of academia, in a sense as a class, not a critique of postmodernism despite the title and conclusion.

@ConiferTravis I was talking more about how philosophy/art (in Deleuze/Baudrillard sense) implies colliding with existing values, implies new ways of thinking, implies not being conformant and question things. But using Deleuze/Baudrillard's discourse for your own benefit, appropriating it, etc. - is kind of the opposite of what the discourse itself is about. I don't remember who said it, but It's more along the lines of "how punk rock was a protest to normal life/values and nowadays children wear t-shirts with punk-rock bands to do exactly the opposite - to fit in society".

@ConiferTravis Also I just remembered the Deleuze's comment in some interview after Anti-Oedipus release, about how he doesn't want to talk about "schizoanalysis", because that would imply "reterritorization" in his terms and he was making the opposite point of constant "deterritorization".
